# how to remove text block (pattern) from a file with sed/awk

Tags: text, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have thousands of text files that I have imported that contain a piece of text that I would like to remove.

It is not just a block of text but a pattern.

```
<!--
# Translator(s):
#
# username1 <email1>
# username2 <email2>
# usernameN <emailN>
#
-->
```

The block if it appears it will have 1 or more users being listed with their email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

This sed solution might work:

```
 sed '/^<!--/,/^-->/{/^<!--/{h;d};H;/^-->/{x;/^<!--\n# Translator(s):\n#\(\n# [^<]*<email[0-9]\+>\)\+\n#\n-->$/!p};d}' file
```

An alternative (perhaps better solution?):

```
sed '/^<!--/{:a;N;/^-->/M!ba;/^<!--\n# Translator(s):\n#\(\n# \w\+ <[^>]\+>\)+\n#\n-->/d}' file
```

This gathers up the lines that start with `<!--` and end with `-->` then pattern matches on the collection i.e. the second line is `# Translator(s):` the third line is `#`, the fourth and perhaps more lines follow `# username <email address>`, the penultimate line is `#` and the last line is `-->`. If a match is made the entire collection is deleted otherwise it is printed as normal.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but it was difficult to parse. Would you be able to add an explanation of what this is doing and why?

Comment: It seems to me that this task is much better accomplished via awk, as shown in answer from user2178077.

Comment: @marbu the sed equivalent is `sed '/^<!--/,/^-->/d' file`

Comment: Ah, ok. That said, tweaking that awk script would still be easier compared to sed solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have another small awk program that accomplish the task in a very few rows of code. It can be used to remove patterns of text from a file. Start as well as stop regexp can be set.

```
# This block is a range pattern and captures all lines between( and including )
# the start '<!--' to the end '-->' and stores the content in record $0. 
# Record $0 contains every line in the range pattern.
# awk -f remove_email.awk yourfile

# The if statement is not needed to accomplish the task, but may be useful.
# It says - if the range patterns in $0 contains a '@' then it will print
# the string "Found an email..." if uncommented.

# command 'next' will discard the content of the current record and search
# for the next record.
# At the same time the awk program begins from the beginning.


/<!--/, /-->/ {
    #if( $0 ~ /@/ ){
        # print "Found an email and removed that!"
    #}
next
}

# This line prints the body of the file to standard output - if not captured in
# the block above.
1 {
    print
}
```

Save the code in 'remove_email.awk' and run it by:
 awk -f remove_email.awk yourfile

Answer (score 0):

for this task you need look-ahead, which is normally done with a parser.

Another solution, but not very efficient would be:

```
sed "s/-->/&\n/;s/<!--/\n&/" file |  awk 'BEGIN {RS = "";FS = "\n"}/username/{print}'
```

HTH Chris

Comment: Why do you think this is inefficient? The scarce resource in IT today is programmer time, not computer efficiency. A one liner with two easy -to-understand statements looks pretty efficient to me; what would a parser solution look like ;-)? Good luck!

Comment: You are right. This solution would be my first try. But for many thousand files this might not be efficient enough.

Comment: Fair enough, I tuned-out on the requirement for thousands of files. I would say if this is a 1 time need for thousands of files, then your solution is still good enough, (inside a for loop). If it's thousands of files a day, then a parser solution may be useful. @armenzg : how critical is run-time for you? P.S. Chris: I did an upvote for your answer, but I don't see a 1 (I do see a yellow arrow). Maybe it will show up later. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i.orig -00 -pe 's/<!--\s+#\s*Translator.*?\s-->//gs' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: -1 This will remove any comment block which starts with #Translator. Example: 
<!--               
# Translator       
this is a comment  
-->

Comment: @Dogbane: Why yes it will: wasn’t that the precise task that was called for?  What’s your complaint?

Comment: First of all it's supposed to match "Translator(s):". Secondly, your solution doesn't take into account usernames and their email addresses.

Comment: @Dogbane: So what?  The problem description doesn't say it has to. I did what was required.  you're not the OP, either.

Comment: According to the problem description: "The block if it appears it will have 1 or more users being listed with their email addresses."

Comment: @dogbane Obviously you and I read these things differently. It says that if it's there, then it will have at least one user.  Therefore you do not have to check for them. You just have to check for the block, which is what I did. If you want to build in a parser for users, then fine, but there is no BNF that spells out the exact contents.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution, if I understood your problem correctly. Save the following to a file called remove_blocks.awk:

```
# See the beginning of the block, mark it
/<!--/ {
    state = "block_started" 
}

# At the end of the block, if the block does not contain email, print
# out the whole block.
/^-->/ {
    if (!block_contains_user_email) {
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            print saved_line[i];
        }
        print
    }

    count = 0
    block_contains_user_email = 0
    state = ""
    next
}

# Encounter a block: save the lines and wait until the end of the block
# to decide if we should print it out
state == "block_started" {
    saved_line[count++] = $0
    if (NF>=3 && $3 ~ /@/) {
        block_contains_user_email = 1
    }
    next
}

# For everything else, print the line
1
```

Assume that your text file is in data.txt (or many files, for that matter):

```
awk -f remove_blocks.awk data.txt
```

The above command will print out everything in the text file, minus the blocks which contain user email.